# ¿Como convertir una variable int a vector?

Tags: java, array

he estado tratando de hacer este problema pero no logro terminarlo
**ingresar número *int* y escribirlo en letra**
*Ejemplo*
150 == ciento cincuenta

Mi mayor problema es que me sale error de compilación al tratar de imprimir los vectores de los números, intuyo que es por que la variable de control (*aux1*) no es **int**, o no la supe convertir

este es mi avance:

```
String unidades [] = {"uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "seis", "siete", "ocho", "nueve"};  
        String decenas []= {"diez", "veinte", "treinta", "cuarenta", "cincuenta", "sesenta", "setenta", "ochenta", "noventa"};  
        String centenas []= {"ciento", "docientos", "trecientos", "cuatrocientos", "quinientos", "seicientos", "setecientos", "ochocientos", "novecientos"};  
        String unidad_m []= {"mil", "dosmil", "tresmil", "cuatromil", "cincomil", "seismil", "sietemil", "ochomil", "nuevemil"};  
        String decena_m []= {"once", "doce", "trece", "catorce", "quince", "dieciseis", "dieciciete", "dieciocho", "diecinueve"};  
        int num, aux1;  
        char aux;  
        System.out.println("escribe un numero");  
        num = var.nextInt();  
        String numero, numero2;  
        numero=Integer.toString(num);  
        numero2 = numero;
        char vec [] = numero2.toCharArray();  
        //una disculpa, hay algunas cariables basura  
        for (int i = vec.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
            aux = vec [i];
            aux1 = (int)aux;
            System.out.println(aux);
            if(vec.length==4){
                System.out.print(decena_m[aux1]);
            }else{
                if(vec.length==3){
                System.out.print(unidad_m[aux1]);
                }else{
                    if(vec.length==2){
                    System.out.print(centenas[aux1]);
                    }else{
                        if(vec.length==1){
                        System.out.print(decenas[1]);
                        }else{
                            if(vec.length==0){
                            System.out.print(unidades[aux1]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

efectivamente uno de los problemas es que aux1 no es el número que quieres, no lo parsea bien. Si haces esto se parsea bien:
`Character.getNumericValue(aux)`, aparte has de restarle 1, dado que en tus arrays los números empiezan en 0.

> aux1 = Character.getNumericValue(aux)-1;

Por otro lado, en los if debes comparar frente a i. En este punto solo faltaría que descompones al reves el número.

Un ejemplo de funcionamiento:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.length; i++) {
        aux = vec [i];
        aux1 = Character.getNumericValue(aux)-1;
        if(i==-1){
            System.out.print(decena_m[aux1]+ ' ');
        }else{
            if(i==0){
            System.out.print(unidad_m[aux1]+ ' ');
            }else{
                if(i==1){
                System.out.print(centenas[aux1]+ ' ');
                }else{
                    if(i==2){
                    System.out.print(decenas[aux1]+ ' ');
                    }else{
                        if(i==3){
                        System.out.print(unidades[aux1]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu programa tiene varios problemas:

1. El primero es a la hora de recorrer el array de vectores, empiezas por el final `( 589 = nueve ochenta quinientos )`
2. El segundo es que no puedes hacer un casting `(int)` del `char`, no te va a dar un resultado correcto, utiliza `Character.getNumericValue(vec[i]) - 1`.
3. Todos los `if else` sin erroneos, `if(vec.length==0)` no puede ocurrir nunca, esto significa que no te han insertado ningún valor!!! si te pongo 587 `vec.length = 3` pero tu if imprime para el caso 3 "unidad_m" por lo cual imprimiría cincomil, cuando debería de ser quinientos.

Aquí tienes tu programa funcional y mejorado sin VARIABLES BASURA XD.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String unidades [] = {"uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "seis", "siete", "ocho", "nueve"};  
        String decenas []= {"diez", "veinte", "treinta", "cuarenta", "cincuenta", "sesenta", "setenta", "ochenta", "noventa"};  
        String centenas []= {"ciento", "docientos", "trecientos", "cuatrocientos", "quinientos", "seicientos", "setecientos", "ochocientos", "novecientos"};  
        String unidad_m []= {"mil", "dosmil", "tresmil", "cuatromil", "cincomil", "seismil", "sietemil", "ochomil", "nuevemil"};  
        String decena_m []= {"once", "doce", "trece", "catorce", "quince", "dieciseis", "dieciciete", "dieciocho", "diecinueve"};  

        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Escribe un numero: ");  
        char vec [] = leer.next().toCharArray();
        int currentVectorValue=0; 

        for (int i = 0; i < vec.length; i++) {
            // Tus arrays de unidades centenas.. empiezan todos en 1 (diez, cien) 
            // pero el array se inicializa en 0, por lo que le quitamos una unidad 
            // al valor recuperado, EXAMPLE: si recuperamos un numero 1, 
            // vamos al vector unidades[0] ya que en la posición 0 está el valor 1
            currentVectorValue = Character.getNumericValue(vec[i]) - 1;

            // Para saber si es unidade decenas centenas etc : vec.length - i
            switch (vec.length - i) {
            case 5:
                System.out.print(decena_m[currentVectorValue]);
                break;
            case 4:
                 System.out.print(unidad_m[currentVectorValue]);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.print(centenas[currentVectorValue]);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.print(decenas[currentVectorValue]);
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.print(unidades[currentVectorValue]);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.print("Out of range");
            }

            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Voy a aportar mi respuesta porque las otras no tienen en cuenta cuando se trata de números que acaban en decenas (11, 12, etc. imprimen "diez uno", "diez dos", etc.)

Ese es el único caso que trato de manera particular dentro del bucle. Para el resto, he cambiado los if's por un switch que me parece mucho más limpio, aparte de usar la condición correcta que me vale para saber qué dígito estoy tratando en la iteración

Por mantener una cierta similitud con lo que ya tienes, no voy a modificar en exceso tu código aunque es mejorable:

```
String unidades[] = { "uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "seis", "siete", "ocho", "nueve" };
String decenas[] = { "diez", "veinte", "treinta", "cuarenta", "cincuenta", "sesenta", "setenta", "ochenta", "noventa" };
String centenas[] = { "ciento", "docientos", "trecientos", "cuatrocientos", "quinientos", "seicientos", "setecientos", "ochocientos", "novecientos" };
String unidad_m[] = { "mil", "dosmil", "tresmil", "cuatromil", "cincomil", "seismil", "sietemil", "ochomil", "nuevemil" };
String decena_m[] = { "diez", "once", "doce", "trece", "catorce", "quince", "dieciseis", "dieciciete", "dieciocho", "diecinueve" };

System.out.println("escribe un numero");
int num = var.nextInt();
String numStr = Integer.toString(num);
for (int i = 0; i < numStr.length(); i++) {
    int aux = Integer.parseInt(numStr.substring(i, i + 1));
    if (aux == 0) continue;

    if ((numStr.length() - i) == 2) {
        if (aux == 1) {
            aux = Integer.parseInt(numStr.substring(i, i + 2));
            System.out.print(decena_m[aux - 10]);
            break;
        }
    }

    switch (numStr.length() - i - 1) {
    case 3:
        System.out.print(unidad_m[aux - 1]);
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.print(centenas[aux - 1]);
        break;
    case 1:
        System.out.print(decenas[aux - 1]);
        break;
    case 0:
        System.out.print(unidades[aux - 1]);
        break;
    }
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```